# Parameter 1 of constructor in package required a single bean, but 2 were found on Webclient creation init

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I 've upgraded my Spring boot version from 3.1.6 to 3.2.3.
My WebFlux application used to work fine until I make this version upgrade.

It is based on several java **modules**.
A Controller calls a Compare service that calls a ClientAPI service which calls an external subsystem.

- Config.java to get the application configuration keys from application.properties. It is in **config module**.
- Controller.java is in **webservice module**. webservice's pom.xml **includes config module** dependency.
- ClientAPI.java and Compare.java are in the same **compute module**. compute's pom.xml **includes config module dependency.**

When I launch the application I have the error below.
I followed the advice in the error log :
*"Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed"*
by adding **@Primary** to the Config.java class. **And It works now.
But I do not understand why It works. I do not understand why I have 2 config beans instead of one. Do not see where the second config comes from.**

```
14:57:56.453 INFO  m.ClientConfig - WebClient Creation init
14:57:56.668 WARN  o.s.b.w.r.c.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - 
cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'compare': Error creating bean with name 'compare': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientAPI': Error creating bean with name 'clientAPI' 
defined in file [C:\git\project\compute\target\classes\mypackage\service\ClientAPI.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'mypackage.config.Config'
 available: expected single matching bean but found 2: config,mypackage.config.Config
14:57:56.698 INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
14:57:56.731 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in mypackage.service.ClientAPI required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - config: defined in file [C:\git\project\config\target\classes\mypackage\config\Config.class]
    - mypackage.config.Config: defined in unknown location

This may be due to missing parameter name information

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Controller.java

```java
import mypackage.service.Compare;
import mypackage.config.Config;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Compare compare;

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    private static final String COMPARE_PATH_SERVICE = "/compare";

    @PostMapping(path = COMPARE_PATH_SERVICE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Response> getResponse(@RequestHeader("requestId") String requestId,
            @RequestBody @Valid InputData inputData) {
                if (config.getMyPersonalKey().equalsIgnoreCase("value")){
                    return compare.compute(requestId, inputData);
                } else {
                    ...
                }

    }
}
```

Compare.java

```java
package mypackage.service;
import mypackage.config.Config;

@Service
public class Compare {

    @Autowired
    ClientAPI clientAPI;

    @Autowired
    Config config;
    
    public Mono<Response> compute(String requestId,@Valid InputData inputData) {
        return clientAPI.sendRequest(requestManagement.buildRequest(requestId, inputData))
                .flatMap(response -> {
                    ...
                        return Mono.just(response);
                });
    }

}
```

ClientAPI.java
Note that WebClient referenced below is built by another class module using "MyWebClient" Qualifier

```java
package mypackage.service;
import mypackage.config.Config;

@Service
public class ClientAPI {

    private WebClient webClient;
    private static final String URI = "/subsystem/v1/compare";
    private String url;
    
    @Autowired
    public ClientAPI(@Qualifier("WebClient") WebClient webClient, Config config) {
        this.url = "https://" + config.getServiceHost() + ":"
                + config.getServicePort() + URI;
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Mono<Response> sendRequest(Request bodyRequest) {
        return this.webClient.post().uri(this.url)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(bodyRequest), Request.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }

}
```

Config.java

```java
package mypackage.config;

@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
//@Primary // Must be uncommented in order to make the execution works
public class Config {

    @Value("${my.personal.key}")
    String myPersonalKey;

    public String getMyPersonalKey() {
        return myPersonalKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you clean the project and build from scratch ?

Comment: Yes, I did a mvn clean to be sure then a mvn clean install through a command line and also on eclipse. Same behaviour